# How to resolve "Unknown Attribute Error" when importing CSV to rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-5

Using the helpful answers from other questions here I set up an import in a controller to add CSV values to a DB in Rails. I continue to get the error below which doesn't give an unknown attribute (although I've quadruple-checked that they match) - it only gives a single quotation mark. Very frustrating. I've rebuilt this a couple times and yet the same error continues to come up. Does anyone have a hunch as to why?

Also, is there an easier/more reliable/more straightforward way to add these CSV values to my rails DB, perhaps using different technologies/apps?

*ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in MatchesController#index*

*unknown attribute '' for Match.*

```
  def index

    require 'csv'

    CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('skedupdate.csv'), :headers => true) do |row|
      Match.create!(row.to_hash)
    end

  end
```

Comment: Are you sure your CSV has been formatted properly?

Comment: can you show the output of `row.to_hash`?

Comment: Try `row.to_hash.delete_if { |k, _| k.blank? }`. You might have empty string as key in your row hash.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, that error happens when you have a column (name) in the row that does not exist in the model, or in your case the row has a key `"` that does not exist.

You should probably print what is in `row.to_hash` to see the contents and to check that all the keys exist in the `Match` model.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error occurs when the headers in the csv are given as per the delveloper's convinience and not as per the column names of the model/particular table.

In your case if you use the exact names in the first row of csv as the name of the database table column it will solve your issue.

For example if there is a **Holiday** table having 2 columns "date" and "holiday" then you have to give the same in the 1st row of your csv file too.
ie. "date" and "holiday".

I solved my issue by using this.Maybe it will work in your case too.